# Aggregating by Customer with logic around dates windowing function

Tags: r

[image]

Could somebody please help me with the below problem. I have this data.frame in the attached image which needed to be processed

Starting from Transaction Code 1- all transactions for a Customer has to be tracked and amount has to be aggregated for a 30-day time frame. And the counter restarts again for the customer once again to create a new aggregate record for another transaction with Transaction code 1 . And the transactions with transaction code 0 or 1 standalone would still be part of output data frame but as an un-aggregated row.

I have tried dplyr, group_by function and summarise but the part I am stuck is including the condition with in the function to get the right answer.

If I type `dput(df)` in the console, I get the following:

```
> dput(df) structure(list(Customer_ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 12L), .Label = c("01/01/2016", "02/01/2016", "02/15/2016", "02/30/2016", "04/01/2016", "04/20/2016", "05/01/2016", "05/05/2016", "06/01/2016", "07/01/2016", "07/15/2016", "10/01/2016"), class = "factor"), Amount = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Transaction_Code = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)), .Names = c("Customer_ID", "date", "Amount", "Transaction_Code"), row.names = c(NA, -12L ), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If your data is in a variable called `df` in r, you would type `dput(df)` in the console, then copy and paste that output into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't understand your question at first, should have paid attention to the windowing function reference.  Here's my attempt, it's not pretty and there's probably a more elegant way with dplyr or data.table package, but it gets the  answer you posted.

```
#your data frame 
x <- structure(list(Customer_ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 12L), .Label =  c("01/01/2016", "02/01/2016", "02/15/2016", "02/28/2016", "04/01/2016", "04/20/2016", "05/01/2016", "05/05/2016", "06/01/2016", "07/01/2016", "07/15/2016", "10/01/2016"), class = "factor"), Amount = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Transaction_Code = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)), .Names = c("Customer_ID", "date", "Amount", "Transaction_Code"), row.names = c(NA, -12L ), class = "data.frame")

#changed date '2/30/2016' to '2/28/2016' to recognize as a real date

x$date <- as.Date(x$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

library(dplyr)

x <- x %>% group_by(Customer_ID) %>%
     #calculate difference between current row date and prev row date (in days)
  mutate(date2 = as.numeric(difftime(date, lag(date,1)))) %>%
     #convert NAs to 0 for start of each customer (needed for cumsum function)
  mutate(date2 = ifelse(is.na(date2), 0, date2)) %>%
     #convert cumsum of days into ranges of 30 & truncate to remove decimals
  mutate(date3 = trunc((cumsum(date2))/30)) %>%
     #re-group by customer and date range period
  group_by(Customer_ID,date3) %>%
     #calculate total Amount per range period
  summarise(totAmt = sum(Amount))

print(x)

Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
Groups: Customer_ID [?]

    Customer_ID date3 totAmt
    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1           1     0      1
2           1     1      3
3           1     4      1
4           1     6      2
5           2     0      2
6           2     1      1
7           3     0      1
8           3     4      1
```

Comment: Thanks Collier for the response. I was able to create a new columm by using month function in lubridate. And after that while I could aggregate amount per customer per month, it doesnt exactly solve my problem. I want to be able to summarise one month from the start of the 1st transaction code =1 for a customer.

Comment: Thank you so much Collier! You sir! is a genius! Appreciate your help.